# ng-change inside dynamically generated html/ionic checkbox not binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

My team and I have been in the process of processing an XML file and composing a **settings** page based on said XML. The elements here are dynamically generated. 
Please find below an example of how the elements are generated.

```
 settings.getToggle = function(label, def){var str1 = '<li class="item lighten orange">';
var str2 = label;  //get label from xml
return str1 + str2 + '<label class="switch orange">' +
                     '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="testmodel" class="switch-input" >' +
                     '<span class="switch-label" data-on="Aan" data-off="Uit"></span>' +
                     '<span class="switch-handle"  ></span></label></li>';};
```

This little piece of code makes sure that when the XML file says: "you have to display a togglebutton", a togglebutton is added to **settings page** and displayed accordingly. There can be multiple buttons of the same kind. In the controller we call this code: (**settings.getToggle(...);**

```
  $(this).find("setting[type='toggle']").each(function () {
                      var label = $(this).find("label").text();
                       var def = $(this).find("default");
                       $("div>.list").append(settings.getToggle(label, def));
                   });
```

Up to here not a problem. The html is generated flawlessly.

At this point we must be able to attach a handler to said elements. And that's where the trouble starts.

Upon adding an ng-change to this html5 checkbox with ionic layout, or even ng-click, ng-model,... you name it, the code does not seem to respond at all.

Example (rest of html -> first code fragment):

```
'<input type="checkbox" ng-click()="testmodel" class="switch-input" >'
```

Coupled with an angular code (in a working, tested controller)

```
    .controller('SettingsController', function ($scope)
{
    $scope.testmodel = function(){
        alert("click");
    };
```

The alert in this case does not pop up. Does anyone know how to fix this? **This is my main and most important question.**

By extension, with me being relatively new to angular I have trouble imagining how to advance from there. I had thought about adding a change listener to each element, and then, getting the name of the element somehow(model?) and putting them in a json var and into localstorage. Does anyone have a more specific idea. I'm actually not sure what to do at this point.

Finally, I'd like to apologize in advance for mistakes in posting and angular. I am in both (stackoverflow and angular) a mere beginner.

Answer (score 1):

change to this without `()` on `ng-click` and append it to the function name `testmodel()`:

```
'<input type="checkbox" ng-click="testmodel()" class="switch-input" >'
```

[See the plnkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/gFWQzXEN6OMYmYRrxoWF?p=preview)

---

if you are going to use `ng-change` directive then in conjunction with this you need to have `ng-model` too:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model='this.checked' ng-change="testmodel()" class="switch-input" >
```

and in the method in the controller:

```
$scope.testmodel = function() {
   alert(this.checked);
};
```

[ng-change with ng-model example plnkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/1CETM1BnoANoT50VEy3G?p=preview)

Comment: Hey, thanks but it still won't work (still not getting into the scope code). It looks like it might be having something to do with my adding it to the page dynamically since, if I add $watch to the scope it registers a change, or a click on loading the page (times 3, I have no clue why).